# Why is "pasarlo teta" ("spend it boob") a good thing in Spanish?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

There is this expression in Spanish: **pasarlo teta**. It means to have a really good time:

> Ayer fuimos al parque de atracciones y nos **lo pasamos teta**.
>   <sub>Yesterday we went to the theme park and we *spent it boob*</sub>

To my understanding, it is used in contexts when you enjoy like a child, but not always is this case.

So I am wondering: why is this expression used? What is its origin? Is it related to the pleasure of an infant while breastfeeding?

Comment: I could understand why boob and having fun could be related. But what about: "Pasarlo bomba". :-|. Is a bomb anything good or funny?

Comment: @Laiv [some bombas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlPS16NeBO0) are quite sexys :D

Comment: I think a better translation would be "had a boob time" but "spend" doesn't sound good to me. Anyway I think this question should be in Spanish since the translation makes no sense.

Comment: Curiously enough (for me at least, as I never heard it before), this figure of speech is in the [Dictionary of the RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZftTurp), as well as _teta_ meaning that something is very good: _"Es teta pura"_.

Comment: @JMVanPelt that's a good one, and interestingly enough, that definition only appears in the last edition of the DRAE (it is missing in the 2001 edition).

Comment: Según el [CREA](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/crea), el primer uso que aparece ahí es de 1981, en el libro "Días de guardar", de Carlos Pérez Merinero. Frases como "nos lo pasábamos teta" y "se lo está pasando teta".

Comment: Now that I think of it, we have another expression: _pasarlo pipa_. Maybe the origin is not related to joy or pleasure, but to entertainment. Eating _pipas_ is just an entertaining pastime, so you could spend the afternoon _comiendo pipas_ or just _pipa_. So the same could be applied here, maybe a sentence such as _pasarse la tarde chupando teta_ applied to an infant was reduced to just _pasarla teta_. The link to the adult world is easy to apply.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Agreed. Funny to see that _pasarlo pipa_ could also have a sexual meaning: _Eso sin olvidar que pipa es equivalente a clítoris, con lo que lo dicho abarca también la materia sexual. Así la juerga es completa_. (from [1de3](http://www.1de3.es/2006/07/31/pasarlo-pipa/))

Comment: Los chilenos lo pasamos **la raja**. Es coloquial pero no es una grosería. En general, para otros usos, con "raja" no nos referimos a la vulva sino a la línea que separa los glúteos, y por extensión al culo completo (o _poto_, como decimos acá). Entonces "pasarlo bien" sería _pasarlo culo_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very difficult to track the origin and motivations of very recent expressions, due to the information going spread faster and faster. In this case, the expression is not present in the CORDE, but it is in [the CREA](http://corpus.rae.es/creanet.html). The first use appears in a 1981 book, "Días de guardar", from Spanish writer Carlos Pérez Merinero. Examples:

> *"Henri era un cliente asiduo de "Le Pelican" y solíamos jugar al juego del camarero y el cliente indeciso con destreza de maestros. Sólo que entonces tenía yo el papel del cuchillero y él el de la víctima propiciatoria. Nos lo **pasábamos teta**."*
>
> *"El cabrón del maître observa la jugada y se lo está **pasando teta**. A lo mejor el muy hijoputa, al ver mi pasividad, me toma por un mariposón."*

The Spanish language has a variety of expressions with the same structure to note that someone is having a good time. Every one of them uses a positive word (in some sense or another), related to entertainment:

- *Pasarlo **bien**.*
- *Pasarlo **[de fábula](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HRcRBBV#CnedrW4)**.*
- *Pasarlo **[pipa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T7Afswj)**.* Maybe related to eating sunflower seeds, or to enjoying some pipe tobacco, or even related to sex, given that "pipa" may refer to the clitoris.
- *Pasarlo **[en grande](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JSEI1iN#223mORn)**.*
- *Pasarlo **[bomba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5pINrRS)**.* Maybe related to the fact that "¡bomba!" was an expression used decades ago before someone made a toast (see 22nd meaning in the definition).

Most of these expressions have been recently included in the DRAE. Some of them are from the 2001 version, others from the 1992 version. So if you think about it, using "[teta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZftTurp#FzeeH9J)" is just a normal evolution, an expression that just nobody knows its origin but fell in grace among the people, because it represents both the child being breastfeeded (related to entertainment and joy) and the adult, more sexual theme of playing with a woman's breasts. But that may place the expression a bit on the *machismo* side, the same case as something *cojonudo* being something good, and a *coñazo* being something bad, only on a lighter level. But this sexual theme regarding the origin of the expression does not mean that you have to use it in sexual contexts, as seen in the examples above, so I am more inclined to think that the expression may have its origins in the entertainment and joy of breastfeeding, as you propose in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I never heard it before... but "teta" is "boob". You like boobs, right? But it must be an expression from a certain area. A more neutral expression will be "la pasamos genial", o "la pasamos increìblemente bien". In some other places (like here, Arg) you could say "la pasamos bomba" -as someone pointed-, and if you ask why bombs are funny... well, they surely are not, but it means that some event was "explosive" in terms of how funny it was, or how uncontrolled in terms of drugs/sex.

Comment: I don't think this is answering my question and would be better placed as a comment. Please refer to [answer] and take the [tour] for a better experience here :)

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Please note that the asker wants to know the origin of the expression, not alternatives. Note also that the question is tagged "España" as the expression is mainly used in that country.

Comment: In fact im answering that. "La pasamos tetas" it's from "boobs", and men like boobs.

Comment: That is just your opinion, but not proven facts. When answering, it's better to seek the origin of an expression, search for the first uses in literature, or consult reliable sources. Note that this site should be closer to the Wikipedia than to opinion-based forums.

Comment: i agree with Fedorqui and CarlosAlejo, this does not answer the question, in fact you spend more effort on explaining "pasarlo bomba" than "pasarlo teta"