# ¿Qué palabras existen en español que tengan acepciones positivas en femenino y negativas en masculino?

Tags: significado, solicitud-de-término

Es un hecho que tras siglos de cultura machista hayamos heredado un idioma que tiene una fuerte inclinación positiva hacia las versiones masculinas de las palabras, cuando estas hacen clara referencia al género humano.

Pongo un ejemplo: hoy en una conversación surgió el tema de que le habían recriminado a una persona el calificar a una mujer de "bruja" (los motivos no vienen al caso). Si miramos el diccionario, vemos las siguientes acepciones para *[bruja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6B6n5sS)* cuando la palabra se usa exclusivamente en femenino:

> 5. f. En los cuentos infantiles o relatos folclóricos, mujer fea y malvada, que tiene poderes mágicos y que, generalmente, puede volar montada en una escoba.
> 6. f. Mujer que parece presentir lo que va a suceder.
> 7. f. coloq. Mujer de aspecto repulsivo.
> 8. f. coloq. Mujer malvada.

Salvo la acepción 6 que parece más neutra, el resto son claramente negativas. En cambio, la acepción cuando se usa exclusivamente en masculino es:

> 4. m. Hechicero supuestamente dotado de poderes mágicos en determinadas culturas.

Un significado positivo, diría yo, ¿quién no querría poseer poderes mágicos?

Otro ejemplo claro es el uso de la palabra *[zorro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cVU9wGT)*:

> 2. m. y f. coloq. Persona muy taimada, astuta y solapada.

Sí, se puede usar en femenino, solo que cuando se usa en femenino suele confundirse con este otro significado aplicado solo a mujeres:

> 7. f. despect. malson. prostituta.

Hay otro ejemplo muy claro que es el que hace acepción a las partes reproductoras: no es lo mismo decir que algo es [cojonudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9igH50S) a que sea un [coñazo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AiN77gb).

Así pues, en aquella conversación mencionada se quedó un tema pendiente que nadie pudo resolver en aquel momento. ¿Existe alguna palabra en español tal que que, aplicada a personas, empleada exclusivamente en femenino signifique algo positivo y empleada exclusivamente en masculino signifique algo negativo? También valdrían ejemplos de palabras que no se apliquen a personas pero hagan clara referencia al hombre (o mujer) o a partes del cuerpo, como el ejemplo de *cojonudo/coñazo*.

Comment: No preguntaste esto, pero para mí es más interesante: cómo contrarrestar este efecto, y retomar la palabra con tono más neutro; y en tu ejemplo, por lo menos, creo que la respuesta es: decir *brujita* en lugar de *bruja*.  De la misma manera que no permito que mis hijos le digan *tonto* a alguien, pero sí *tontuelito*.  (Versión suavizada.)

Comment: @aparente001 preguntar cómo contrarrestar eso puede ser una pregunta complicada de responder, además de bordear el _offtopic_. Aunque tal vez podamos plantearla más adelante, he preferido empezar por una pregunta más sencilla y directa.

Comment: Perdón, no quería criticar la pregunta, y además, no se pueden proponer alternativas a palabras que no se han identificado todavía.  Nota, voté a favor de la pregunta.  Es interesante lo que observaste de *bruja/o*, y también me dio a pensar en el cambio en el uso de *witch* con el adviento del feminismo....

Comment: @aparente001 no te preocupes, no lo tomé como una crítica, sino como un comentario constructivo. :-)

Comment: @walen - Ejemplo: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/feb/24/witch-symbol-feminist-power-azealia-banks ("The task of reclaiming the witch is a fundamentally poetic one").

Comment: Una pregunta para los españoles: ¿puede ser el par _chulo / chula_ un ejemplo de esto? Porque veo que para ustedes el masculino es "proxeneta", pero no sé si eso se aplica también al femenino (dado el caso de la canción de Bosé...)

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta que leí la pregunta al revés de lo que es.  Entendí que había que buscar palabras positivas en lo masculino y negativeas y lo femenino.

Comment: @Rodrigo lo he comprobado [en el diccionario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=93FnsRh) y, aunque efectivamente el significado de "proxeneta" se aplica únicamente en masculino y hace referencia al sexo masculino, la palabra no tiene una acepción que se aplique solo en femenino y que sea positiva.

Comment: El ejemplo del *cojonudo* y el *coñazo* nunca me ha gustado porque, por ejemplo, si llamamos *cojonazos* a alguien no le estamos diciendo nada positivo, precisamente. O *huevón* en algunos países. Pero la pregunta en sí me parece muy interesante.

Comment: @walen entiendo vuestra argumentación, pero la acepción de "chulo" como "que obra con chulería" se aplica también en masculino, no es exclusiva del género femenino, que es lo que buscaba. De hecho, si me dicen que "tal tío es un chulo" o que "va de chulo" no me viene a la cabeza la definición de "proxeneta" salvo que el contexto así lo indique. En todo caso, yo animo a Rodrigo a que plantee esa opción como respuesta y que la gente la vote y comente, que para eso estamos (y yo no pretendo estar en posesión de la verdad absoluta).

Comment: Cc @Rodrigo del último comentario (por favor, plantea "chulo/a" como respuesta para que la gente la pueda votar y comentar, que necesitamos más discusión aquí). :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Me llega [vía Twitter](https://twitter.com/raul_decast/status/886951315150131200) una respuesta a esta pregunta: **[señorito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcT6x6x)**.

Usada en femenino (*señorita*) puede significar:

> 4. f. Término de cortesía que se aplica a la mujer soltera.
>
> 5. f. Tratamiento de cortesía que se da a maestras de escuela, profesoras, o también a otras muchas mujeres que desempeñan algún servicio, como secretarias, empleadas de la administración o del comercio, etc.

Sin embargo, usada en masculino tiene una connotación ligeramente peyorativa:

> 3. m. coloq. Joven acomodado y ocioso.

Ejemplo del CORDE:

> *El temor de no enojar al señorito los enfrena el gobierno de sus antojos, y aun se ponen de parte de sus viciosas inclinaciones. Porque no llore el niño, dejan verter lágrimas a su conciencia.*
>
> Diego de Torres Villarroel, "Visiones y visitas de Torres con Don Francisco de Quevedo por la corte", 1727-1728 (España).

Answer (score 4):

En la línea de la propuesta de *[señorito](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21526/5481)* yo voy a proponer la propia palabra "femenino".

Dados los múltiples significados de "[femenino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HjghBNR)"

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la mujer. La categoría femenina del torneo.
> 2. adj. Propio de la mujer. Un gesto femenino.
> 3. adj. **Que posee características atribuidas a la mujer**. Su abuela fue una mujer muy femenina.

Al decir de alguien del sexo femenino que es *femenina*, el adjetivo actúa casi como epíteto (se ve claro en el tercer ejemplo de las entradas del diccionario). Es algo con connotaciones positivas.

Por el contrario, aplicado a un hombre, le resta "hombría". Esto se ve mejor en la palabra "[afeminado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0wtotJy)"

> 1. adj. Dicho de un hombre: Que en su persona, modo de hablar, acciones o adornos se parece a las mujeres
> 2. adj. Dicho de un hombre: homosexual.

Y en este caso ese "*homosexual*", o el tener esos rasgos "característicos de las mujeres" tiene connotaciones peyorativas.

Answer (score 3):

Pregunta curiosa, si las hay, pero hace pensar.

Para que un sustantivo pueda referirse a una persona debe ser un sustantivo personal o el nombre de un animal o una cosa a los que se atribuya una característica que, al menos figurativamente, pueda aplicarse a personas.

Todos, o casi todos los ejemplos que voy a mencionar pertenecen al habla coloquial de estas latitudes. Otros compañeros foristas sabrán decir si los encuentran o no familiares, o inclusive citar otros.

Los sustantivos que se me ocurren masculinos corresponden a animales a los que se atribuye una cualidad negativa:

- **loro**: *Habla como un loro* (demasiado) - *Es un loro* (esp. dicho de mujeres de nariz grande y curva, cual pico de loro)
- **perro**: *Es un perro cantando* (desafinado, dicho de hombre o mujer) / *Es un perro jugando al fútbol* (poco hábil) (Ref. "perra", todos conocemos su significado negativo referido a mujer.)
- **moscardón**: *Sácame este moscardón de encima* (persona densa, pesada, asfixiante)
- **zángano** (imbécil)
- **gato**: *Esa mina es un gato* (prostituta)
- **lobo** (entre corderos): persona peligrosa (dicho de mujer, "loba" es positivo y significa "inusualmente seductora, atractiva")
- **ganso** (tonto)
- **caballo** (bruto, sin modales). También: *Entró como un caballo* (cayó fácilmente en la trampa) ("yegua" es un insulto para mujer similar a "perra")
- **burro** (poco inteligente)

No obstante, debo reconocer que la tendencia machista está presente en la lengua, y es así que encontramos masculinos con cualidades positivas y femeninos equivalentes con rasgos negativos:

- **toro / vaca**: *Ese niño es un toro* (fuerte, saludable) / *María está hecha una vaca* (obesa)
- **gallo / gallina**: "gallo" (y sobre todo "gallito") también se usa en un sentido negativo para significar "vanidoso, altanero". "gallina" puede decirse de un hombre cobarde.

Luego tenemos nombres de animales de género único que, según las cualidades que se les asignan, implicarán características positivas o negativas en referencia tanto a hombres como mujeres: **rata** (amarrete), **víbora** (traicionero), **chacal** (depravado), **tortuga** (lento), etc.

En cuanto a cosas, me vienen a la mente **roca** (duro de entendimiento) y **tabla** (dicho de una mujer sin busto).

Comment: It is curious but probably not very helpful that the witch/wizard example is the only one I can think of in English other than animal ones (like bitch, cow, ...)

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta. Sin embargo, no estoy seguro de que los ejemplos de animales propuestos sean lo que busco. Si bien es cierto que se aplican en masculino, sus significados se pueden aplicar a las mujeres: _esa mujer me persigue cual moscardón_, _fulana habla como una cotorra_ (en vez de loro), _qué tía más perra_ se puede entender como su variante masculina, etc. No veo un caso claro como el de _bruja_ pero al contrario.

Comment: El ejemplo que más probabilidades tenía era el de _lobo/a_, pero según el diccionario el significado de "persona atractiva" se aplica tanto a hombres como a mujeres.

Answer (score 3):

Te propongo ***chapero*** que, por definición, cuando se usa como insulto solo se hace en masculino:

> [**chapero**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=chapero)
>   1. m. jerg. Homosexual masculino que ejerce la prostitución.

Mientras que en femenino quiere decir otra cosa totalmente distinta:

> [**chapera**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=chapera)
>   De *chapa*.
>   1. f. Constr. Plano inclinado hecho con maderos unidos por medio de travesaños sobrepuestos y clavados, que se usa en las obras en sustitución de escaleras.

Saliendo del DRAE pero siguiendo con la temática homosexual (que se presta bastante a este tipo de distinción), otro término que solo en masculino tiene connotaciones negativas sería ***palomo cojo***. La definición, aunque sospecho que casi todos la conocemos ya, la voy a coger del Diccionario Gay:

> [**palomo cojo**](http://www.moscasdecolores.com/es/serie-gay-slang/diccionario-gay-palomo-cojo-espana)
>
> Al parecer el tema está en que **los pobres palomos cojos no se pueden reproducir porque necesitan las dos patas para pisar (montar) a la paloma**, con solo una pata no se pueden agarrar ni tampoco realizar el cortejo previo característico de la especie.
>
> La expresión "**palomo cojo**" pertenece a la categoría del “concepto de torcido” junto a otras palabras y expresiones como la inglesa *queer*, las españolas *desviado* o *tortillera*, la palabra árabe *šāḏ*, o la noruega *skeiv*, todas con el sentido de torcido, anormal, malogrado, desviado o estropeado.

Por su parte, "**paloma**" en femenino, según el DRAE, no es más que una persona tranquila:

> [**palomo, ma**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=palomo)
>   4. **f.** Persona de genio apacible y quieto.

Por último, y por buscar un ejemplo que use las partes del cuerpo, es conocida y reconocida la expresión "pasarlo **teta**" como sinónimo de pasarlo muy bien:

> [**teta**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=teta)
>   5. f. coloq. Cosa muy buena. Es teta pura.

Mientras que en masculino no hay equivalencia, de puro aburrido que es el cuerpo del hombre :D

Comment: Buena opción, pero te falla el que la acepción femenina no se aplica a personas, y no tiene una connotación negativa. Creo que se me pasó especificar eso en la pregunta, tal vez lo di por entendido, voy a corregirla.

Comment: Si te refieres a frases como "pasarlo teta", habría que preguntarse por qué "pasarlo teta" es positivo. Pregunto algo similar [en esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21126/12637).

Comment: Perdón, acabo de recordar que lo de "pasarlo teta" [ya se preguntó antes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18361/12637). :-D En todo caso, te agradezco mucho el esfuerzo que estás haciendo por proponer opciones y abrir debate. :-)

Comment: Ya que a veces la connotación positiva o negativa viene del hecho de que determinadas cualidades se consideran tradicionalmente positivas en el hombre, pero negativas en la mujer, tal vez *paloma/o* sea una buena respuesta a la pregunta original. Si decimos de un hombre que es un *palomo*, estamos diciendo que es ingenuo y fácil de engañar, mientras que decir que una mujer es una *paloma* indica que es dulce y no maliciosa.

Comment: Algo que me resulta curioso es que estos ejemplos hacen referencia de forma negativa a la homosexualidad masculina.Me resulta curioso porque cuando se habla de forma negativa de la homosexualidad suele ser precisamente por la feminidad del hombre en cuestión.

Answer (score 3):

Propongo

> **[chulo, la](http://dle.rae.es/?id=93FnsRh)**
>
> Del it. *ciullo* 'niño', y este acort. de *fanciullo*.
>
> **1**. adj. Que habla y obra con chulería. U. t. c. s.
>
> **2**. adj. coloq. Lindo, bonito, gracioso.
>
> **8**. m. rufián (‖ hombre dedicado al tráfico de la prostitución).

Como puede verse, en masculino puede referirse a un proxeneta (me imagino que con un tono peyorativo). Entonces habría una importante diferencia entre *mi novia es chula* y *mi novio es chulo*. Ambos pueden significar lo mismo (mi novia/o es guapa/o), pero el masculino es anfibológico, creo que hay que usarlo con cuidado...

---

**Edición** a propósito de los comentarios:

Estoy de acuerdo en que ésta puede no ser una muy buena respuesta, y me excuso diciendo que *chulo* no es una palabra que se use en mi país, así que yo mismo no tengo claro su valor peyorativo.

Pero quisiera mostrar el paralelismo que se nota con el primer ejemplo de la pregunta, el femenino ***bruja***.

> Mi esposo es bruj**o**: no cabe duda: él practica la brujería.
>
> Mi esposa es bruj**a**: puede significar tanto que ella practica la brujería (algo que puede ser bueno o malo, depende del contexto) como que sea malvada, mandona o tirana (algo negativo, sin duda).
>
> Mi esposo es chul**o**: puede significar tanto que él es físicamente atractivo (positivo) como que se aprovecha y lucra de las mujeres que lo rodean (negativo).
>
> Mi esposa es chul**a**: sin duda: ella es atractiva.

O sea, tanto *brujo* como *chula* tienen un significado inequívoco, mientras que *bruja* y *chulo* tienen un doble sentido, cargado a lo negativo (aunque, por supuesto, uno puede ser bruja/chulo en el peor de los sentidos, sentirse orgulloso de ello y recibir aplausos).

Comment: Hasta ahora esta es la única respuesta que **realmente** responde a la pregunta.

Comment: coincido con @walen, el uso de proxeneta de la palabra chulo no suele venir como insulto, de hecho en un entorno machista se podría considerar hasta como un halago por la facilidad con las mujeres.

Answer (score 2):

Posiblemente, en El Salvador, *bicho/bicha* (aunque la forma femenina lleva connotaciones negativas además de la neutral):

> [**bicho**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=bicho)...
>
> 6. m. despect. coloq. *El Salv. y Hond.* Niño, muchacho.

> [**bicha**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=bicha)...
>
> 5. f. coloq. *El Salv.* novia

Comment: [Animal Names Used as Insults and Derogation in Polish and Spanish](https://revistascientificas.us.es/index.php/PH/article/view/1554)

Answer (score 1):

### Por ejemplo, en Colombia respecto a **Chimbo** y **Chimba**

En Colombia, *chimba* es un termino **callejero**, mayoritariamente usada por ñeros (nacos === México).

*Chimba* define a algo como "buenísimo", grande, amplio, fantastico, impresionante, etc. Define como algo **apreciable**. Aunque claro, añadiendo sarcásmo es todo lo contrario:

> *No pues, tan chimba no?*.

**Es un término muy, pero muy diferente de "Chimbo"**.

Ésta última define como algo de muy mala calidad, o una porquería. Sucede que en otros paises se confunde "chimbo" con "chimba" sólo porque *no hay diferencia ampliamente notoria en la palabra*.

Dependiendo del contexto en el que se use, porque *"Qué chimba"* puede ser o **no** sarcástico. Es fácilmente notable cuando **estás hablando personalmente**.

Puedo decir:

> *uff, qué chimba éste celular!*.

Con ello puedo indicar que **me gusta** el celular, o que **simplemente estoy burlandome del mismo**.

- El tono de voz define el sarcasmo.

Normalmente ésta terminología está empezando a ser rechazada por la sociedad, en especial estratos igual o mayores a 3, poca gente de estratos 1, y 2 nota ésto algo muy grosero e irrespetuoso.

Ésta clase de palabras tienen muchísimo uso entre amigos, o conocidos muy importantes, es algo muy normal. Teniendo en cuenta el anterior párrafo.

Algunos artistas como **Juanes** siempre destacan el lenguaje de Colombia y las variedades del mismo. Por estilo de demostrar cómo se habla en Colombia es aceptable, de lo contrario podría no ser así. Como algunos dicen, hábla y con ello defines quién eres.

- Cabe destacar que éstas palabras aplican para todo, objetos,
  animales, persona y/o cosas.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! ¿Podrías aclarar si esta palabra se puede aplicar a personas? ¿O es solo para cosas?

Comment: Aplica para todo. :)

Comment: Y la cuestión principal: ¿tiene un sentido exclusivamente negativo cuando se aplica a mujeres, y positivo cuando se aplica a hombres? Nótese que no hablo de cuando la palabra tiene género masculino o femenino, sino de cuando aplica a hombres o mujeres.

Comment: Frecuentemente, el uso de éstas palabras es para objetos. Como el ejemplo que escribí. Para responder a lo que me dices, cuando es "Chimba" en Colombia es definido como algo bueno, siempre y cuando no haya sarcasmo, y "Chimbo" cuando es algo de muy mala calidad, siempre y cuando tampoco haya sarcasmo. El uso de sarcasmo le da el significado contrario.

Comment: Entiendo. La pregunta va más bien enfocada a buscar términos que sean positivos aplicados a mujeres y negativos a hombres (creo que antes lo dije al revés). ¡Pero gracias por tu aportación!

Comment: En Colombia no se toma en cuenta el hecho de que Chimbo sea malo porque es define masculino, o Chimba bueno porque define femenino. Es simplemente un término cualitativo de muy baja educación.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero [**marica**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OPMBIVV). Las acepciones masculinas son todas despectivas, malsonantes y se usan como insulto:

> 1. adj. despect. malson. afeminado (‖ que se parece a las mujeres). U. m. c. s. m.
> 2. adj. despect. malson. Dicho de un hombre: Apocado, falto de coraje, pusilánime o medroso. U. m. c. s. m.
> 3. adj. despect. malson. Dicho de un hombre: homosexual. U. m. c. s. m. U. t. c. insulto.

mientras que la acepción femenina no lo es:

> 4. f. urraca (‖ ave similar al cuervo).