# ¿Cuál es el origen y verdadero significado de la expresión "de puta madre"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

Alguien en Twitter me propuso la expresión "de puta madre" como respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21106/12637). En principio parecía una buena opción, dado que la usamos para describir algo bueno, y hace mención al sexo femenino. Sin embargo, luego me paré a pensar, dado que es de esas expresiones que igual en principio querían decir una cosa, y luego se vaciaron de significado para pasar a querer decir otra.

Ahora mismo significa esto:

> **[de puta madre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NpxaH7S#GYPISfU)**
>
> 1. loc. adj. vulg. Muy bueno. U. t. c. loc. adv.

Pero si lo meditamos, ¿qué quería decir la expresión inicialmente? ¿Que nos lo vamos a pasar igual de bien que si encontráramos una prostituta que nos hiciera un servicio a todos y gratis? ¿Que algo es igual de bueno que los servicios de la madre de X, que es muy ligera de cascos?

¿Cómo se originó la expresión? ¿Cuál fue la intención original de usar la palabra "puta" en la misma? Y como reflexión: ¿se podría considerar pues una expresión machista? ¿O le estoy tratando de buscar los tres pies al gato?

Comment: Como ya sabéis el español coloquial tiene expresiones muy originales. La expresión “de puta madre” es una de las que más sorprende a los estudiante de español. Al combinar palabras tan diferentes como “madre” y “puta” la mayoría creen que el significado es un insulto, el cual existe y sería “tu puta madre”.
En cambio, los españoles usan “de puta madre” para decir que algo es muy bueno. Por ejemplo, “mi amiga es de puta madre”, “la película es de puta madre” o “la fiesta estuvo de puta madre”. Puede usarse con el verbo ser y con el verbo estar.

Comment: ¿Será como *Qué bárbaro*?  ¿Y en inglés *bad*?

Comment: Curiosamente los mexicanos no dicen _de puta madre_ sino _padrísimo_.

Comment: ¿Tal vez porque las cosas que **"están de puta madre"** también suelen **"ser cojonudas?"**

Answer (score 4):

La expresión "[hijo de puta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijo_de_puta)" es quizás el insulto más popular en español. Tan popular y tan antiguo es, que su uso "irónico-invertido", como encomio, es también popular y antiguo: se encuentra documentado desde el siglo XVI.

Por ejemplo, en [este artículo](http://www.contrastiva.it/baul_contrastivo/dati/barbero/Ridruejo_modos%20de%20hablar_Miranda.pdf)  ("Los  “modos de hablar” en las *Osservationi della lingua castigliana* (1566) de Giovanni Miranda" - Emilio Ridruejo - 2008) se menciona el estudio sobre la lengua española que hizo un italiano en 1566. Entre otras cosas, en el rubro de los "usos irónicos" del lenguaje, le llama la atención que la voz ofensiva "hideputa" se use muchas veces como ponderación. Se mencionan ocurrencias en la Celestina y otras obras literarias. Sobre todo en el [Quijote (2da parte, cap 13)](http://cervantes.uah.es/quijote/quij0076.htm), cuando el escudero se lo explica a Sancho Panza :

> ¿Cómo y no sabe que cuando algún caballero da una buena lanzada al
>   toro en la plaza, o cuando alguna persona hace alguna cosa bien hecha,
>   suele decir el vulgo: "¡Oh hideputa, puto, y qué bien que lo ha
>   hecho!?" Y aquello que parece vituperio, en aquel término, es alabanza
>   notable

y finalmente Sancho Panza reconoce que

> no es deshonra llamar hijo de puta a nadie, cuando cae debajo del
>   entendimiento de alabarle.

Esto de dar vuelta por completo el significado de un insulto, por algún mecanismo irónico, sigue siendo popular. Y en España que te digan "Eres el puto amo" es una alabanza (que en otros lugares podría provocar una reacción ofendida, a lo Sancho Panza).

Por el mismo mecanismo, y como el uso insultante de "hijo de puta" pretende denigrar al destinatario (no por una cuestión machista, sino por cuestiones de prosapia y calidad familiar - como "bastardo") decir de una cosa que es "de puta madre" significa (en el uso irónico invertido) exaltarla.

Comment: ¿Podría ser que la expresión "de puta madre" fuera una simplificación de "hijo de puta madre" usada en ese tono irónico de alabanza?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Creo que eso es indudable. Decir "de puta madre" es lo mismo que "hijo de puta". Aunque, por algún extraño motivo, lo segundo no se usa para cosas, solo para personas.

Comment: @Charlie Pienso que se refería a las **hijas** de puta madre, que solían ser como la madre pero menos consumidas…

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo veo más una expresión que venga de un pensamiento religioso, como a la madre María tratada como "*puta*", como a la Magdalena, las dos Marías, las dos tratadas probablemente con el mismo status. ¿ Qué pensaría José de su mujer?

Y aún así, y dejando de lado tales pensamientos, pero teniéndolos en cuenta, cuentan, ser hijo de mujer de tal grandeza, es el mejor improperio que puedan decirte.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24881)