# ¿Se usa solamente en Perú "puta madre" como palabrota?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, vulgaridades, perú

Mis compañeros de Perú suelen decir "Puta madre" cuando se enfadan o molestan.
Algo que equivale a "mierda" o "joder".

En España los españoles dicen que eso suena muy raro y así no se dice. Lo mismo ocurre con la gente de otros países hispanohablantes: dicen que tampoco en su país se dice así.

Nadie tiene problema con entender el contexto cuando lo digo pero nadie lo usa menos gente de Perú.

Las preguntas son:

- ¿Cómo suele ser en vuestros países?
- ¿Tenéis la misma experiencia que yo?
- ¿Tengo razón que así dicen solo los peruanos?

Answer (score 4):

En España, el sentido de "puta madre" depende en realidad de qué palabras vayan antes, e incluso de la intención y contexto.

Así, *"**de** puta madre"* o simplemente *"puta madre"* quiere decir que algo es muy bueno.
Por el contrario, *"**su** puta madre"* es un insulto...
casi siempre (puedes leer más sobre esto aquí mismo: [¿Cuál es el origen y verdadero significado de la expresión "de puta madre"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21126/13628)).

Entonces, sí que es cierto que, a veces, en España se usa "su puta madre" sin referirse a nadie en particular, solo como expresión de fastidio, similar al "mierda" o "joder" que indicas.
Por ejemplo: se te cae un martillo en un pie y exclamas: *"¡Su puta madre, qué dolor!"*. Técnicamente te refieres al martillo, pero el martillo no tiene madre y lo sabes; es solo un expletivo más.

Pero "puta madre", a secas, siempre se interpreta como si tuviera "de" delante y, por tanto, siempre en positivo.
La única manera en que se podría usar en negativo, sería a base de sarcasmo: *"Genial, se me ha vuelto a perder la cartera, (de) puta madre. A ver cómo pago el taxi ahora"*.

Comment: *su puta madre* tiene otro matiz, cuando no quieres hacer algo ni loco: *Va a subir a esa grúa su puta madre*, sustituible también por *tu puta madre*

Answer (score 2):

Los casos en Chile son los siguientes:

- **¡Puta madre...!**: alargando un poco la [a] de madre. Es una interjección de enfado suave, no muy ofensiva. Es lo te que dirías a ti mismo si no le pusiste azúcar al café (y te gusta el café con azúcar) o cuando sufres alguna decepción entre gente de confianza. Es equivalente a *puta la weá*. Por lo tanto, respondiendo a una de tus preguntas, el uso de *puta madre* como expresión de enfado no es exclusivamente peruano, también lo decimos los chilenos.
- Esto es **de puta madre**: se usa para decir que algo es o está bueno, o es de características superlativas. *La nueva consola es de puta madre* significa que es excelente. *Es queso está de puta madre* quiere decir que su sabor está muy intenso. Es el mismo uso que @walen indica para España.
- Él es **un puta madre**: quiere decir que la persona es desvergonzada, promiscua o usa un lenguaje obsceno. Es más o menos equivalente a *fresco* y a *chuchetas*.

Comment: Muy similar en Colombia pero cabe anotar que su uso no es recomendado en situaciones formales. Es común, informal y algo vulgar. Si se está en un contexto laboral, formal o con desconocidos es preferible usar sinónimos.

Comment: 'De puta madre' solo se lo he escuchado a argentinos.

Answer (score 1):

Por experiencia personal puedo indicar que en Guatemala los contextos en que se utiliza es como grosería e insulto.

Por lo que suele utilizarse para indicar enfado de la misma forma que en Perú.

Answer (score 0):

En México es coloquial y se usa mucho entre los jóvenes.. hay variantes y todo un ensayo sobre el uso de "madre"..además esta esl uso "se dio en la madre" cuando se chocas en un carro, "ni madres" como sinónimo de no lo voy a hacer, esta "de poca madre" que esta muy bien, " es una madre" ..es algo insignificante,,, " me salió con una madre" ..me salió con un pretexto o algo irrisorio.."  "le dieron en la madre", lo golpearon.. y el "hijo de su pin.. madre"  como un insulto..