# Connotaciones de "hacer padre" frente a "hacer madre" a alguien

Tags: expresiones

En algunas otras preguntas (y respuestas) como en [¿Qué palabras existen en español que tengan acepciones positivas en femenino y negativas en masculino?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21106/5481) o [Why is “pasarlo teta” (“spend it boob”) a good thing in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18361/5481) hemos destacado que el castellano tiene a veces connotaciones muy distintas para ciertos términos o expresiones dependiendo  del género de las palabras, con una fuerte inclinación positiva hacia las versiones masculinas de las palabras y negativa para las contrapartidas femeninas.

Un compañero de clase me dijo una vez que la expresión "hacer *padre* a alguien" es positiva. Es algo bueno porque ser padre (tener un hijo) es algo bueno. Sin embargo para esta persona "hacer *madre* a alguien" era algo malo. Cuando le pregunté el porqué me dijo que "hacer madre" es sinónimo "de que te joden" y jugaba con esa doble acepción de "[joder](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVjNCIs)" para el acto sexual y para molestar, fastidiar, estropear, etc.

Básicamente, si una madre tiene un hijo es que la han "jodido", mientras que a un padre no.

Esta persona decía cosas como:

> (buscando sitio para aparcar otro coche deja un hueco) Mira, ese se marcha. Me acaba de hacer padre.
>
> Esos temas no me los he mirado par el examen. Como caiga una pregunta sobre ellos me van a hacer madre.

Es decir, que no aplicaba la expresión en base al género del hablante o del aludido, sino a si la situación era favorable o no.

No he podido encontrar casi nada al respecto de las locuciones "hacer padre"/"hacer madre". ¿Hay algo de cierto en el uso de esas expresiones con esas connotaciones? ¿Es realmente "hacer padre" algo bueno pero "hacer madre" algo malo?

Comment: No había oído esas expresiones. "Hacer un hijo" sí pero "hacer padre/madre" no. ¿Dónde se usa eso?

Comment: @walen para mi "hacer un hijo" si es figurado también. "Me has hecho un hijo" se usa como que te han hecho un gran favor.

Comment: Nunca escuché estas expresiones. Sí *hacer un hijo* y *hacer mujer*, con connotaciones sexuales figurativas y casi siempre degradantes.

Comment: Me resulta muy curioso porque yo más bien las he oído en sentido absolutamente contrario, se supone que "las madres quieren tener hijos" (quieren serlo), y en cambio los padres no (como que quieren "intentarlo" pero sin la consecuencia, por lo que llegar a tener el hijo se convierte en lo que se dice un "marrón"). Sorprendente.

Answer (score 1):

me suena a pocho... jamás escuché esas expresiones. En México decir "se rompió esa madre" se entiende como "se rompió esa porqueria". Mientras que "que padre la pasamos" significa "que bien que la pasamos". Pero "hacer padre/hacer madre" nunca lo escuché

Ojo que en muchísimos otros paises de habla hispana estas expresiones mexicanas no existen ni se entienden.