# ¿Por qué "Pasarlo teta" es singular?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, plurales

Sólo he encontrado esta [publicación relacionada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18361/why-is-pasarlo-teta-spend-it-boob-a-good-thing-in-spanish) y no acaba de aclarar mi duda.

¿Por qué en la expresión "pasarlo teta", **teta** es singular cuando lo común en los humanos (y mamíferos) es que sean más de una (plural)?

Answer (score 2):

Si buscas [teta](https://dle.rae.es/teta?m=form) en el DLE todas las frases usan teta y not tetas incluso.

> dar la teta

1. loc. verb. coloq. Dar de mamar.

Solo das una teta al niño

Comment: Entonces, ¿entiendo que "Pasarlo teta" viene del símil del niño que le dan la teta y se lo pasa bien?